# Exportar en excel pero solo algunas columnas

Tags: angular, primeng, xls

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial: http://primefaces.org/primeng/table/export

Puedo exportar en excel en mi aplicación pero me exporta el ID y es algo que no me gustaria exportar, en el ejemplo del tutorial también lo exporta.

this.regions = [{id:1, name:"Test1"}, {id:2, name:"Test2"}]

```
exportExcel() {
import("xlsx").then(xlsx => {
    const worksheet = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(this.regions);
    const workbook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = xlsx.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });

    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, "regions");
});
}

saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
let EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
let EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
    type: EXCEL_TYPE
});
FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
}
```

Puedo recorrer this.regions y solo usar el name, pero queria saber si existe alguna forma óptima para no hacer un for

Answer (score 0):

Si ese es tu requerimiento, no veo problema alguno de usar un loop para excluir las propiedades que no quieres exportar. Podrías simplemente mapear el objeto incluyendo solo la información que necesitas:

```
const regions = this.regions.map((region) => ({ name: region.name }));
```